# Ошибка в JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: HystModal is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь сделать модальное окошка по плагину hystModal.
Вот JS код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
const myModal = new HystModal({
    linkAttributeName: "data-hystmodal",
    // настройки (не обязательно), см. API
});
```

});

Вот HTML код:

```
<a href="#" data-hystmodal="#myModal">Показать окно</a>
        <div class="hystmodal" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="hystmodal__wrap">
            <div class="hystmodal__window" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
                <button data-hystclose class="hystmodal__close">Закрыть</button>
                <!-- Ваш HTML код модального окна -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Все что нужно для работы. Сам я подключил их библиотеку. Но все равно пишет ошибку о том что  HystModal не определен. В чем может быть проблема?

Вот их официальный сайт: https://addmorescripts.github.io/hystModal/index_ru.html
Там написано что нужно сделать. Сам все шаги сделал.

Все делаю ради учение.

Comment: Подключение скрипта где в HTML? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="hystmodal.min.css">
 
<script src="hystmodal.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Rudi, Здравствуйте. Это тоже делал. Ладно уш. Спасибо за помощь. Буду сам разбираться. Думаю сам сделать Модальное окно.